# SqlBulkCopy to stored procedure using Type Table

Tags: c#, sql

I want to use a bulkCopy to stored procedure then use merge to upsert.

here is my stored procedure

```
@bulkLdapGroup  [TEMP_LDAP_GROUP] readonly

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

merge into [SECURITY_CUBE].[dbo].[LDAP_GROUP] as Target
using @bulkLdapGroup as Source
on Target.[GROUP_NAME]=Source.[GROUP_NAME]
when matched then 
update set Target.[DESCRIPTION]=Source.[DESCRIPTION], Target.[WHEN_CREATED] = Source.[WHEN_CREATED],Target.[UPDATED_DATE]= GetDate()
when not matched then 
insert ([GROUP_NAME],[DESCRIPTION],[WHEN_CREATED],[UPDATED_DATE]) values (Source.[GROUP_NAME],Source.[DESCRIPTION],Source.[WHEN_CREATED],GetDate());


end
```

How can i pass a table in using bulkCopy and execute this stored procedure?
In the c# code, i want to pass Datatable as parameter, then execute this stored procedure.

Comment: Don't use SqlBulkCopy, use a table valued parameter SqlParameter (with SqlDbType.Structured or whatever) and invoke the SP the way you normally would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Table-value parameter store procedure and use C# code to pass your Datatable to store procedure.

```
// Create a DataTable 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(...)
// Configure the SqlCommand and SqlParameter.
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "your TVP store procedure", connection);
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@tvp", dt);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Comment: TVP works good for less rows, like 1000. You can also use XML parameter. In C# code, you structure your data into XML and pass XML to your store procedure @xml, in store procedure, you convert you xml back to temp table.

Comment: I'm passing 900 000 rows
and i want to do an upsert

Comment: You'd better to break your 900,000 to smaller chunk, and upsert(merge) chunk by chunk in different transaction. If you have to complete all 900,000 in one transaction, then I strongly suggest you first chunk by chunk insert them into temp table, then from your temp table to do one-time upsert(merge) for itegrity purpose and roll back as a whole.

Comment: I use TVPs with thousands of rows with moderate success. I say "moderate" because in the first call to the SP, SQL Server will "parameter sniff" (I believe that is the first term) the number of rows in the TVP that's used and build an execution plan from this. This does not work well for my stored procedures which take a variable number of rows (1 to 10,000) because the plan generated for 1 row is terrible for 10,000. So the SPs, regrettably, have `WITH RECOMPILE`.